# Is Shamir's Secret Sharing Scheme insecure for larger field?

Tags: provable-security, secret-sharing, information-theory

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing#Solution), if you are using shamir's secret sharing scheme with a field of order $p$, "High values of $p$ are risky because Eve knows that the chance for $f(x)\pmod{p}=f(x)$ increases with a higher $p$". Is this true? It seems wrong.

Comment: what that means is f(x) is smaller than p, so mod p does not change the value

Comment: @RichieFrame Well, yeah. But why would $f(x) \pmod{p} = f(x)$ hurt security?

Comment: when that is the case it is like you are not using the mod p at all, an attacker can skip that step completely, substantially reducing the effort to guess values if points are known

Comment: @RichieFrame Calculating moduluses wasn't that hard to begin with. Besides, Shamir's secret sharing is informationally secure, so it isn't a matter of effort anyway.

Comment: "It seems wrong" -> it is wrong; there's no security issue with large $p$ values.

Comment: @poncho yeah, I think I'll help fix that article at some point.

Comment: @RichieFrame You are wrong. There is no problem at all using large (or small) $p$. When $f(x)$ is chosen at random except for the constant term, then there is no issue.